# How to fix security certificate in a Twilio app

Tags: twilio

I need help meeting Twilio's requirement for a security certificate. My site was set up about seven-years ago with a self signed certificate which worked okay till March 2017. What I need is someone that can fix the problem or instructions a monkey (myself) can understand that tells me step by step what I need to do.

Although I did write most of the PHP code it was with a lot of hand holding from some great folks at Twilio that have long since departed. Fortunately, the only feature impacted on my site is the functionality to delete voice recordings.

I'm at a total loss in understanding the Twilio documentation, where to get a certificate, what kind I need, what changes to make on my hosted website, etc. The application is used as part of a simple after hours answering service and for appointment reminders. Perhaps someone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: You've two options, I think - either hire someone or do it yourself. The latter would need for this question to be edited with the actual problem, e.g. error logs, a failure message of some kind, what things you found when you tried web-searching for the error, etc. Perhaps also your Twilio web account contains logs, assuming there is such a thing?

Comment: Failing all that, perhaps you could approach one of the (good) freelancer websites, such as AirPair, and get an expert for an hour or two who can do the work for you directly on your server.